# Counterexample of Sylow subgroups of a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $P$ be a Sylow subgroup of a finite group $G$. Let $N$ be a subgroup of $G$.

$(1)$ If $N$ is normal in $G$, then $P\cap N$ is a Sylow subgroup  of $N$. I have proved this.

$(2)$ In general, is $P\cap N$ a Sylow subgroup of $N$? I think this is not right since the proof does not hold. How to give a counterexample? I am quite confused. Thanks.

Comment: What examples have you tried? What happens if $G$ has two distinct $p$-Sylow subgroups $P$ and $Q$ and you try with $N = Q$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $S \in Syl_p(H)$, then $S=H \cap P$ for some $P \in Syl_p(G)$. But the converse is not true: try to find the Sylow 2-subgroups of $S_3 \times S_3$ and intersect these with (a copy of) its subgroup $C_2 \times S_3$ of order 12.

Comment: Can you give a reference for your first claim?

Comment: This is fairly easy to prove:  if $S \in Syl_p(H)$, then $S$ is contained in some $P \in Syl_p(G)$. Hence $S \subseteq P \cap H$, so $|P \cap H| \geq |S|$. Reversely, $H \cap P$ is a $p$-subgroup of $H$, and must be contained in a some $T \in Syl_p(H)$. But $T$ is conjugate to $S$, whence $|S|=|T|$. This yields $|P \cap H| \leq |S|$. Hence $P \cap H=S$.

Comment: Thanks! That made it clear.

Comment: Conversely, can we say that if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $P\in Syl_p(G)$, then $P\cap H\in Syl_p(H)$?

Comment: No, see my counterexample above. It is true if $H$ is normal in $G$.

Answer (score 6):

Tobias and Nicky already answered your question, but we can actually classify the counterexamples amongst finite groups.

### Classification

Kegel (1962) tried to understand exactly those subgroups $N$ that work. He called such subgroups $p$-subnormal if it worked for all the Sylow $p$-subgroups.

**Definition:** Let $G$ be a group, and $N \leq G$ a subgroup.

1. $N$ is said to be **$p$-subnormal** in $G$ iff $P \cap N$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N$ for every Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ of $G$.
2. $N$ is said to be **subnormal** in $G$ iff there is a sequence of subgroups $N = N_0 \unlhd N_1 \unlhd \ldots \unlhd N_k = G$ each normal in the next, starting at $N$ and ending at $G$

The Kegel–Wielandt conjecture was that a subgroup was $p$-subnormal for all primes $p$ iff the subgroup was subnormal. Kleidman (1991) proved this:

**Theorem:** If $G$ is a finite group and $N \leq G$, then the following are equivalent:

1. $N$ is $p$-subnormal in $G$ for all primes $p$
2. $N$ is **subnormal**

$2 \implies 1$ is easy to prove form your (1), and $1 \implies 2$ points exactly where counterexamples occur: amongst finite groups, exactly in the non-nilpotent groups.

### Smallest example

The smallest non-nilpotent group is the non-abelian group of order 6. It has more than one Sylow 2-subgroup, for instance $N$ and $P$. Their intersection is $P \cap N = 1$ and is too small to be a Sylow 2-subgroup of $N$. This is Tobias's example. Nicky's example is less trivial.

### Bibliography

- Kegel, Otto H.
  “Sylow-Gruppen und Subnormalteiler endlicher Gruppen.”
  Math. Z. 78 (1962) 205–221.
  MR[147527](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=147527)
  DOI:[10.1007/BF01195169](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01195169)
- Wielandt, Helmut.
  “Zusammengesetzte Gruppen: Hölders Programm heute.”
  *The Santa Cruz Conference on Finite Groups (Univ. California, Santa Cruz, Calif., 1979)*,
  pp. 161–173, Proc. Sympos. Pure Math., 37, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, R.I., 1980.
  MR[604575](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=604575)
- Kleidman, Peter B.
  “A proof of the Kegel-Wielandt conjecture on subnormal subgroups.”
  Ann. of Math. (2) 133 (1991), no. 2, 369–428.
  MR[1097243](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1097243)
  DOI:[10.2307/2944342](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2944342)

Comment: Jack, nice addition! I noticed it just now (that is 9 months later ...)